# Firebase 'bytesTransferred': Property 'bytesTransferred' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, firebase-storage

**What I'm using**

- Angular
- Firebase

**What I have**

- An upload service that allows me to upload to firebase storage and the realtime database
- This has been working fine for weeks

**The Issue**

- This morning it doesn't work.
- I haven't changed anything to do with this file or it's components
- The only thing I have changed was a firebase npm install to try get some other nonsense to work
- This has literally halted my project completely
- My service now displays the error on build of:

> [ts] Property 'bytesTransferred' does not exist on type 'Object'
>
> [ts] Property 'totalBytes' does not exist on type 'Object'.
>
> Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Unsubscribe'.
>     Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.

**Questions**

- Does anyone know why this error message is displayed all of a sudden?

**My Upload Service**

```js
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Upload } from './upload';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AuthService } from '../../user/auth.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

// Routes
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectsAddService implements OnDestroy {
  private _subscription: Subscription;
  private basePath: string = '/site_photo';
  uploads: FirebaseListObservable<Upload[]>;

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase, 
    private authService: AuthService, 
     private router: Router
  ) { }






  getUploads(query = {}) {
    this.uploads = this.db.list(this.basePath, {
      query: query
    });
    return this.uploads
  }


  deleteUpload(upload: Upload) {
    this.deleteFileData(upload.$key)
      .then(() => {
        this.deleteFileStorage(upload.name)
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  // Writes the file details to the realtime db
  private deleteFileData(key: string) {
    return this.db.list(`${this.basePath}/`).remove(key);
  }

  // Firebase files must have unique names in their respective storage dir
  // So the name serves as a unique key
  private deleteFileStorage(name: string) {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${name}`).delete()
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this._subscription) {
      this._subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  submitForm(title: string, reference: string, date: string, auditorName: string, newCompanyName: string, upload: Upload) {
    this._subscription = this.authService.user.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {

        // The User ID of the current user
        var userId = user.uid;

        // Generate a new firebase key to be used for the Project, Project List, Project Members and Storage References
        var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('project_list').push().key;

        // Create a reference to the firebase storage
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        const uploadTask = storageRef.child('site_photo/' + user.uid + '/' + newPostKey + '/site_photo').put(upload.file);

        uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
          (snapshot) => {
            // upload in progress
            upload.progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          },
          (error) => {
            // upload failed
            console.log(error)
          },
          () => {
            // upload success
            upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
            upload.name = upload.file.name

            // Data to be added to the 'Project' node
            var albumDetails = {
              album_title: title,
              label_name: newCompanyName,
              album_photo: upload.url
            }

            // Data to be added to the 'Project_list' node
            var albumList = {
              label_name: newCompanyName,
              album_photo: upload.url
            }

            // Data to be added to the 'Project_members' node
            var userList = {
              [userId]: true
            }

            // Group the updates to the associated firebase nodes
            var updates = {};
            updates['/album/' + user.uid + '/' + newPostKey] = projectsDetails;
            updates['/album_list/' + user.uid + '/' + newPostKey] = projectsList;
            updates['/project_members/' + newPostKey] = userList;


            // Once the image has been successfully uploaded, make an update to the realtime database
            this.saveToRealtimeDatabase(updates);

            this.router.navigate(['projects']);
          }
        );

      }

    });


  }

  // Perform an atomic Multi-Path update
  private saveToRealtimeDatabase(updates) {
    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
  }


}
```

Any help here would be HUGELY appreciated. Completely baffed by this.

---

---

---

**UPDATE**

I've noticed that if I comment out the following code, it compiles correctly. I just get an incorrect reading of the progress of the upload.

```js
          (snapshot) => {
            // upload in progress
            upload.progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          },
          (error) => {
            // upload failed
            console.log(error)
          },
```

**SECOND UPDATE**
The following works, but it feels a bit odd. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
        var snapshotRef = snapshot as firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot;
        var bytesTransferred = (snapshotRef).bytesTransferred;
        var totalBytes = (snapshotRef).totalBytes;
        upload.progress = (bytesTransferred / totalBytes) * 100;
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue, haven't found a solution yet either

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace your code snippet with below code.

```
uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
  (snapshot) =>  {
    upload.progress = (uploadTask.snapshot.bytesTransferred / uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log(upload.progress);
  },
```

Comment: I have an error in unsubscribe part. I get this error:   `  Argument of **type '() => void '** is not assignable to parameter of type 'Unsubscribe'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.  `

Comment: could you please answer my question as well. I fixed the first part using your solution. @Hasi

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough about typescript or this package to explain exactly what is going on, but at least I can fix it.

Apparently the complete callback in the new version does no longer accept any as a return type, but only undefined. I think it has something to do with the default Unsubscribe that returns undefined. In your code you can fix the error by manually returning undefined in your callback.

```
() => {
    console.log('upload complete');
    return undefined;
}
```

Typescript can apparently not infer the type of the snapshot in the first callback, you will need to specify it manually as well, you can use a typecast or you can call a seperate function from your callback.

```
 console.log((snapshot as firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot).bytesTransferred);
```

I would appreciate it if someone has a more in depth explanation.

Comment: Hey Alfred, I'm glad someone else had this issue. I was loosing my mind! the 'return undefined', in my code above, would that be placed under 'this.router.navigate(['projects']);'? Where would your second line of code go in my example above?

Comment: I'm also very confused why this decided to break this morning when it's been working for so long.

Comment: Yes the return undefined should go under that line.
You need to change 
    snapshot.bytesTransferred
To 
    (snapshot as firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot).bytesTransferred
And do the same with totalBytes

Comment: What about the 'console.log' part? I wonder if the error has anything to do with angular cli versions, or firebase installs.

Comment: the console log was just in my own code to test if the casting worked, you don't need that and probably don't want that in production code

Comment: ah ok. Even if i returned undefined, I have the same error about totalBytes and bytesTransferred.

Comment: I made a 'second update' to the above using what you mentioned. This is the only way I've managed to get it to work. As you said, it doesn't feel like 'production' code.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Fixed by setting the type of the snapshot. This is in typescript.

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) => {
    upload.progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem 
i resolved it by declaring uploadtask and all other variables before the constructor and then simply using this.uploadTask to use it

```
storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    file : any;
   uploadTask: any;



this.uploadTask = this.storageRef.child('images/${this.file.name}').put(this.file,metadata);

        this.uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, function(snapshot){...}
```

Comment: BUT
My upload gets stuck at "Upload is Running" even after the image is uploaded

Comment: I suggest Alfred_P's answer is 100% correct and it should be marked correct as it is the only way out!